# How to make changes to an egg/setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I've installed this source: https://github.com/scragg0x/FFXIV-Scraper/blob/master/setup.py

But I'm fairly unfamiliar with the file structure. I'm looking to change some of the code (which should impact the `lodestoner` CLI). What file do I need to edit, and what would I need to re-run to apply to the CLI? For example, I see an `__init__.py`, would I edit that and simply re-run `setup.py`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're installing it.  If you want to distribute it to other people, you should update the version number, which will let tools like `pip` correctly upgrade the package.

Additionally, if you're not the original author of the package and you're thinking about forking the project and distributing it, it's usually best to change the package name (even if you are going to keep the same namespace and import names).  See [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) and [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.1.0) as an example of this.

If you're just doing it for testing, you can run the `setup.py` script manually and it should reinstall the package regardless of the version number.

```
python setup.py install
```

If you want to make continuous changes to the package for development without having to reinstall it each time, you can install the package so that it runs from your development location.

```
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: I'm not the author, I'm just looking to make a minor change on my local system.